# Exe running in C # windows service

Tags: windows, service

I am writing with c # windows service. Tickers in this manner when it is working without a problem.

```
bool processIsRunning(string process)
{
    return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(process).Length != 0);
}     
if (!processIsRunning("notepad"))
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
}
```

When the codes are not working this way.

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") + "\\path.txt");
string path = oku.ReadLine();
string processname = Path.GetFileName("notepad");
if (processIsRunning(processname) == false)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
}
```

I'm getting the name of the program and the program path from registry.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, but there are some possible problems if the code you have posted is your entire relevant code.

Your `StreamReader` is called `read`, yet you are trying to read from a stream called `oku`?

Also, you haven't shown that you actually close your `StreamReader, you would be better of using a`using` block to make sure that your Stream is properly closed and disposed of.

```
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") + "\\path.txt"))
{
    string path = read.ReadLine();
    string processname = Path.GetFileName("notepad");
    if (processIsRunning(processname) == false)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Task Manager program is running. Does not display on the screen.

Comment: What do you need help with? I can't remember this far back :)